# Can't get data from parsed JSON (Nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have JSON file:

```
{
    "Abilities": {
        "ability_base": {
            ...
        },
        "some_data": {
            ...
        },
    }
}
```

Parsed it with:

`var obj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./npc_abilities.json'));`

And try to get some data from it. I made:

```
for (var key in obj) {
    console.log(obj.Abilities.ability_base);
}
```

It shows me data from `"ability base" {...}`, it is correct behavior. But when I tried to get all keys, of my Abilities object:

```
for (var key in obj) {
    console.log(obj.Abilities[key]);
}
```

It shows me "undefined" in console. Why? How can I get all objects inside Abilities?

Comment: It should be `for (var key in obj.Abilities)` - you're getting the keys from the parent object and trying to use them with the child object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're iterating over the wrong object. You can try this

```js
var obj = {
  "Abilities": {
    "ability_base": {
      a: 1
    },
    "some_data": {
      b: 2
    },
  }
};

// Iterating over obj
for (var key in obj) {
  console.log("Key: ", key);
  console.log(obj.Abilities[key]);
}

console.log("*****************************");

// Need to iterate over obj.Abilities
for (var key in obj.Abilities) {
  console.log("Key: ", key);
  console.log(obj.Abilities[key]);
}
```

Notice the `console.log` of the `key` in both the cases. I believe you require the second `for` loop and not the first one.